# Windows phone 8 dialor

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am pretty new to Windows phone development. I want to create an application that will be displayed as an option to the user, when the user dial a number or select 'call' option from a saved contact, for routing the call through that application. The application first dial some number to connect to a specific service provider and then dial the number on the selected contact or the number that the user dials to make the call. I had an experiment with the PhoneCallTask but not succeeded. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no way to put your app's shortcut in `Phone` app. I assume what you are looking for is a call interceptor app. Currently, the builds till WP8.1 don't support it. There are possibilities of such API in the final Windows 10 build though.

Please use a search engine to look for API limitations first and then ask a question in SO.